# Problem in connecting oracle instance from one of the fresh machine

Tags: c#

We have an issue related to connecting the Oracle database 19 c / 12c from one of the Windows 2016 machine build from AWS

The exception we are getting is "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client"

Our application is using Oracle.DataAccess.dll to connect the oracle database.  Along with the application build we have added these below binaries so that customers are not required to install the ODAC explicitly
oraociei12.dll
oci.dll
oraons.dll
OraOps12.dll

Our application is running in most of the Windows machine(s) and also with freshly build machine from AWS.
Expect for one of the particular Windows Machine they call as Production, there we are facing an issue. We tried all the possible solution provided in the Stackoverflow and others site, Tries are like
Installing the ODAC explicitly
Checking with GAC
Adding the environment variable
And other possible ways  suggested over the net.

Can anybody help here what I am missing here?

[image]

[image]

Comment: you can also check the similar post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client

Comment: I have already gone through that post but it did not worked for me. With out any oracle client / ODAC installation only with the required DLL that I mentioned is working in most of the machines. But at one particular machine I am have this issue. The Windows machine they call it as Production which is newly build has issue but the similar one were they call it as Development it is working perfectly.