# OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Tags: c#, oracle

My .Net framework is 4.6.1 and The Oracle Client is 11.2.0 version. I changed my machine, it used to be working properly. Now, I really don't get it why the Oracle Connection on my C# code is not working anymore. I'm using Oracle.DataAccess to manage oracle connection. This is a web api program on .Net C#.[image]

This the error that I'm getting:
System.TypeInitializationException occurred
HResult=0x80131534
Message=The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.
OracleException: The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

I would like to ask for your help and step by step solution. I've tried to search for solutions, apparently, it's not directing me to the right answer. Thank you!

Comment: This error can have several reasons. I think the most common is: you mixed 32-bit and 64-bit assemblies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client/25412992#25412992

Comment: Thank you for the the information @WernfriedDomscheit, it solved my problem.