# EF Core migration error while using Oracle with ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm not familiar with ASP.NET Core, and I'm currently learning EF Core for the first time. Please help me....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXTW9.png)

Model class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace efcore_oracle
{
    public class Bora
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id123 { get; set; }
    
        public string Name123 { get; set; }
        public string Email123 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`DbContext`:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace efcore_oracle
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    { 
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions\<DataContext\> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Bora> Boras { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.Net;

namespace efcore_oracle
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string\[\] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
    
            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
    
            // 추가
            var connectionString = "Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE); User Id = myid!!; Password = mypw!!;";
    
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(
                dbContextOptions => dbContextOptions
                   .UseOracle(connectionString).LogTo(Console.WriteLine, LogLevel.Information)
            );
    
            var app = builder.Build();
    
            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }
    
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllers();
    
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
PM> dotnet ef database update
Build started...
Build succeeded.
```

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[0]
> 2023-10-16 09:22:39.792191 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)
> OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  OracleException.Number: 351
> 2023-10-16 09:22:39.792191 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)
> OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  OracleException.Number: 351
>
> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[0]
> 2023-10-16 09:22:39.800394 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)
> OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x0000015F): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVTokens.PopLiteral()
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.GetContext(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadTopLevelNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.CreateNVPair(String nvString)
> at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
> at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> 2023-10-16 09:22:39.800394 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x0000015F): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVTokens.PopLiteral()
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.GetContext(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadTopLevelNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.CreateNVPair(String nvString)
> at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
> at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x0000015F): ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVTokens.PopLiteral()
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.GetContext(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadTopLevelNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
> at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.CreateNVPair(String nvString)
> at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
> at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)
> at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
> at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch) at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
> at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
> at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.OracleDatabaseCreator.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
> ORA-00351: ?ㅽ듃?뚰겕 ?쇱씠釉뚮윭由? ?대쫫-媛믪뿉???덈Т ?대Ⅸ 臾몄옄?????쒖떆?낅땲??

I want to execute `dotnet ef database update`.

I successfully ran `dotnet ef migrations bora` in the terminal, and `dotnet ef migrations add bora` also completed successfully, resulting in the creation of migration files.

However, I'm encountering this error when running `dotnet ef database`

Comment: [I believe the issue related  to the ODP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/659341/the-provider-is-not-compatible-with-the-version-of-oracle-client), could you check the oracle version and download the correct DOP and Oracle Instant Client .